# Find Duplicate in Array

Tags: java, arrays

Given a read-only array of `n + 1` integers between `1` and `n`, find one number that repeats in linear time using less than `O(n)` space and traversing the stream sequentially `O(1)` times. If there are multiple possible answers, output any one.

If there is no duplicate, output `-1`

Input: `[3 4 1 4 1]`

Output : `1 or 4`

Why is the following code not working?

```
public int repeatedNumber(final List<Integer> a) {
        Collections.sort(a);
        for (int i = 0; i < a.size() - 1; i++) {
            if (a.get(i) == a.get(i + 1)) {
                return a.get(i);
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: because you're not iterating values to compare through all set

Comment: Please don't ask for a review or *why* your code is not working. That is asking "us" to do what is expected, at the minimum, of you.

Comment: Also, please tag it with a specific language. Looks like you're using Java; add it or the correct one.

Comment: I don't think I need to go through the whole list because it's already sorted. If any integer repeats itself they'll be in the adjacent position and code will catch it.

Comment: Sorry, I am new here. I am just confused why this approach is not working.

Comment: What output are you getting? -1?

Comment: For some test cases I tried myself, I am getting right output but for the test case by compiler, I am getting -1, which is wrong.

Comment: Give examples of in/output. It's preferred that you show some effort and reasoning. Like => "I tried [this] and expected [that] but got [some other thing]." That will go a long way.

Comment: @JatinGupta check the answer you won't be get getting 4 because 1 is iterated first due to .sort() and then function exits

Comment: Test case compiler is running is an arraylist of 600 elements. Can't put that here because of character limit

Comment: Yeah, I know @AviSangray .. By my code, I'll only get the smallest repeating number. Question states that I can return any repeating number and output will be valid

Comment: @JatinGupta code is working fine. it does outputs 1. could you please elaborate on your issue

Comment: Test case compiler is running is an arraylist of 600 elements. While output should be 134 to that list but somehow my code is returning -1. Can't put that here because of character limit

Answer (score 0):

so two things:-
use just .size() instead of .size() - 1

```
   public static int repeatedNumber(final List<Integer> a) {
    Collections.sort(a);
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {

        if (a.get(i) == a.get(i + 1)) {
            return a.get(i);
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
  Integer listy[] = {3,4,1,4,1 };

  List iyu = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(listy));


  System.out.println(repeatedNumber(iyu));
```

you won't get 4 output anyway because it returns(exits) on matching "1" so doesn't reaches 4  in the list
and you won't

Comment: I only have to return any of the one repeating number. My code will always return smallest repeating number.

Comment: @JatinGupta well why don't you try watching output for each iteration and check to see  
System.out.println(a.get(i) " : " a.get(i + 1));

Comment: @JatinGupta and also output the list to make sure it's sorted. just some handy debugging

Comment: Ok, thanks I'll try. But I read the question statement again and it says that this list is read-only, so I think modifying it in any way including sorting, is not to be done and that's why the compiler is showing error

Answer (score 0):

Ok I'll explain it with the sample test case

5
2 3 1 2 3

So the algorithm say we should run a loop with the body

`a[a[i]%n] = a[a[i]%n] + n;`

Lets dry run it

1. For i = 0 , a[2%5] = a[2%5] + 5, modified_array a[2,3,6,2,3]
2. For i = 1 , a[3%5] = a[3%5] + 5, modified_array a[2,3,6,7,3]
3. For i = 2 , a[6%5] = a[6%5] + 5, modified_array a[2,6,6,7,3]
4. For i = 3 , a[7%5] = a[7%5] + 5, modified_array a[2,6,11,7,3]
5. For i = 4 , a[3%5] = a[3%5] + 5, modified_array a[2,6,11,12,3]

Now for every(a[i]/n > 1) we push the i in the result vector because the frequency of i in array is given by a[i]/n

Now let us try without using a[i]%n

- For i = 0 , a[2] = a[2] + 5, modified_array a[2,3,6,2,3]
- For i = 1 , a[3] = a[3] + 5, modified_array a[2,3,6,7,3]
- For i = 2 , a[6] = a[6] + 5, 
  this is where we'll run into problems as we'll get garbage value for a[6]

So in `a[a[i]%n] = a[a[i]%n] + n;` we are saving the frequency of a[i] at the position i=a[i] and the modulus is used to preserve the original value

The key condition in this question is 0 < a[i] < n-1

I hope this clears your doubts...

```
    vector<int> duplicates(int a[], int n) {
        vector<int> result;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            int index = a[i] % n;
            a[index] += n;
        }
        int c=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (a[i]/n > 1)
            {
                result.push_back(i);
                c++;
            }
        }
        if(c==0) result.push_back(-1);
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe

```
public int repeatedNumber(final List<Integer> a) {
    Collections.sort(a);
    for (int i = 1; i < a.size(); i++) {
        if (a.get(i) == a.get(i - 1)) {
            return a.get(i);
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

You will get `Index out of bounds` Exception if that is Java with your code. Secondly, I would cache size.

Looks like homework to me though.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils ...and nada, mate. Just an observation. There is plenty of discussion about that on meta therefore won't start new one.

Comment: There's no benefit to that snippet. You're only assuming without reason for the assumption. They don't know why you care that it's homework and you're seemingly speaking for *US*.

Comment: Not homework. I am studying Data Structures & Algorithms for job interviews and been scratching my head for an hour or so over this. I think my logic is correct but test case is not running.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils LOL, what exactly makes you think I am speaking for anyone else but myself? That's rhetoric question if you were tempted to reply.... Whatever, good night.

Comment: @JatinGupta OK, sorry then.

Comment: You're making a meaningless comment for no apparent reason then to, idk, undermine their post. You may not realize or care, but when you post here or interact with other users, you are representing the community; you're representing *US*. It's a gotcha, cheap-shot, or however you'd prefer it be stated.